# How to create a materialized view in Oracle EBS 12.2 that refreshed daily at 5PM

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, oracle-ebs

I am trying to create a materialized view in the xxcus custom schema in an 11g Oracle database on a Oracle E-Business Suite 12.2 installation that is editioned. I would like to access this materialized view from an Oracle Apex installation on the xxcus schema and also via a database link. Oracle recommends that database links use their own schema called xxcus_ro.

With EBS you have to create materialized views in a special way according to Oracle Support Doc ID 1577661.1. First you create a view:

```
create or replace view apps.xxar_invoice_totals_mv# as       
   select rctv.trx_number invoice_number,
          rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_name,
          rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_num,
          sum(rctla.extended_amount) invoice_total
   from   apps.ra_customer_trx_v       rctv,
          ar.ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctla
   where  rctla.customer_trx_id = rctv.customer_trx_id
   group  by rctv.trx_number,
          rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_name,
          rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_num;
```

Then you run `exec ad_zd_mview.upgrade('APPS', 'XXAR_INVOICE_TOTALS_MV')` to create a materialized view the way Oracle EBS wants it to be created.

While this works and creates the materialized view, the view it creates uses `REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND` and there is no parameters for `ad_zd_mview.upgrade` to specify a refresh interval. The Doc ID 1577661.1 also does not mention anything about refresh.

My original materialized view that I wanted to create before finding out about Doc ID 1577661.1:

```
create materialized view xxcus.xxar_invoice_totals_mv as
tablespace APPS_TS_TX_DATA
pctused    40
pctfree    10
initrans   2
maxtrans   255
storage    (
            initial          40k
            next             40k
            minextents       1
            maxextents       unlimited
            pctincrease      0
            freelists        1
            freelist groups  1
            buffer_pool      default
           )
nocache
logging
noparallel
build immediate
refresh complete
start with to_date('7-Sep-2020 10:25:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
next to_date(to_char(sysdate+1,'yyyy-mon-dd')||' 20:10','yyyy-mon-dd HH24:MI')
as
select rctv.trx_number invoice_number,
       rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_name,
       rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_num,
       sum(rctla.extended_amount) invoice_total
from   apps.ra_customer_trx_v       rctv,
       ar.ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctla
where  rctla.customer_trx_id = rctv.customer_trx_id
group  by rctv.trx_number,
       rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_name,
       rctv.rac_bill_to_customer_num;
```

How can I create a materialized view that refreshes daily at 5AM inside of EBS 12.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW XXAR_INVOICE_TOTALS_MV
 REFRESH COMPLETE
 NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 5;
```

unless you don't have the following restrictions on your materialized view:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#i1007007